# Check a checkbox in an HTML page with Python 3.5 & Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, checkbox, web-scraping

I am trying to select all checkboxes that appear on an HTML page with Python 3.5 and Selenium. The final goal is obviously to manipulate them, but I can't even manage to select them properly.

I can't just give you the exact URL, because it's a special page on eBay and you need to be connected to see it. So, here's how to access the web page that interest me:

1. Go to https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll
2. Create an account or Log In
3. Go to http://cgi5.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SellHub3 when connected
4. Type in "iPhone" or any brand you want, it doesn't matter, and click on the "Start selling" button.
5. You are on the page.

You can see that, if you type 'iPhone', eBay proposes you to choose from one of all of these categories:

> **Mobile Phones & Communication**
>
> Mobile & Smart Phones
>
> Mobile Phone & PDA Accessories > Other Mobile Phone Accessories
>
> Other Phones
>
> Smart Watches
>
> Mobile Phone & PDA Accessories > Cables & Adapters
>
> Mobile Phone Parts
>
> Mobile Phone & PDA Accessories > Chargers & Docks
>
> Mobile Phone & PDA Accessories > Headsets
>
> Mobile Phone & PDA Accessories > Cases & Covers
>
> **Wholesale & Job Lots**
>
> Other Wholesale & Job Lots

**My goal is to tick the first checkbox, no matter how much checkboxes there are on the page. I just want to check the very first one. It's simple as that. In this example, that means check the checkbox "Mobile & Smart Phones".**

I tried the XPATH method:

> checkBox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@type='checkbox']")

But when I try print(checkBox), it returns [ ] (=nothing). It's strange because in Firefox this XPATH give me just exactly what I need.

I also tried to select it with the class name:

> checkBox = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('inpChkBox')

But again, it results in nothing when I try to print it.

How can I just generate a list of all the checkboxes on the page, in order to manipulate them after?

**It seems like the id, name, etc of all checkboxes are unique and generated automatically, so I can't just select them by their ID, or Value, or Name. I need something that detects all checkboxes in the page and put them in a list.**

Thanks for any help

Comment: are you sure you're in the correct `frame` before you fetch the element?

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I'm new to Selenium, so I'm not sure about that. How can I make sure it's the correct frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also not sure if that page has frames, but I usually do it this way.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

before I scrape elements. Then I use this function to query the element.

```
def get_element(by_arg, by_method=By.ID):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, MAX_TIMEOUT).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((by_method, by_arg))
       )
```

so for your case it would be.

```
check_box = get_element(".//input[@type='checkbox']", By.XPATH)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how to check the first checkbox please? I just tried your code and I added 'check_box[0].click()' and it doesnt work, it raises this error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

You were indeed right, the correct iframe was not chosen and so I wasn't able to interact with its checkboxes.

> driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('catFrame'))
>   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.idtTopSm tr input').click()

But do you know why the page still doesn't "listen" to the checkbox click? I mean, the blue button is supposed to turn blue and be "clickable" once a checkbox has been clicked.