# Check a checkbox in an HTML page with Python 3.7

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, checkbox

I am trying to select the checkbox that appear on an HTML page with Python 3.7 and Selenium. The final goal is obviously to manipulate them, but I can't even manage to select it properly. The url is the following:

https://eurexmargins.prod.dbgservice.com/

Prior to that post, I carefully read the related [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351007/check-a-checkbox-in-an-html-page-with-python-3-5-selenium#_=_) but the proposed solutions don't work in my case (I get an ElementClickInterceptedException).

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC       

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

MAX_TIMEOUT = 20

def get_element(by_arg, by_method=By.ID):
    return WebDriverWait(browser, MAX_TIMEOUT).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((by_method, by_arg))
       )

browser.switch_to_default_content()

browser.get("https://eurexmargins.prod.dbgservice.com/")


get_element(".//input[@type='checkbox']", By.XPATH).click()


time.sleep(15)
browser.quit()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what have you tried to get the state of the checkbox. Please show us some code, so that we see what might not work.

Comment: Also, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213417/select-check-box-using-selenium-with-python) might help.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried that returns the error.

Comment: Thanks! I just added the code

Comment: @Pierre Cornilleau Don't forget to mark the answer that solves your issue to help others who may be having the same issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this is not your regular check box. See below for a working example.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://eurexmargins.prod.dbgservice.com/terms")

element_toclick = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//mat-checkbox[@id='mat-checkbox-1']")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

element_toclick.click()
```